# Modify element property on key press

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to hook up an event that shows a WPF Popup control when a TextBox has focus and a keyboard shortcut is clicked. For instance. When typing in the TextBox field, the user can press ALT+H for help, to get a popup dialog showing input help. Pressing ALT+H "outside" the TextBox should not open the popup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try something like in [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656359/how-do-i-suppress-menu-keyboard-shortcut-keydown-handling-in-wpf

Comment: Can the approach use standard events?

Comment: @EugenSoft: I can't see how that relates to my case. What are you thinking?

Comment: @StaWho: What do you meen by "standard events"?

Comment: Simply capturing `GotFocus()` and `LostFocus()`, setting a flag and showing popup `OnKeyUp()` only if flag is set (i.e. box in focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a job for an `Attached Event`.

From MSDN:

> The concept of
>   an attached event enables you to add a handler for a particular event
>   to an arbitrary element rather than to an element that actually
>   defines or inherits the event. In this case, neither the object
>   potentially raising the event nor the destination handling instance
>   defines or otherwise "owns" the event.

You can find details [here, on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use command binding:

```
  ApplicationCommands.Help.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.H, ModifierKeys.Alt));
  this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Help, Help_Executed, Help_Enabled));
```

In function Help_Executed do some operations
In function Help_Enabled check if textbox selected, do e.CanExecute = true;

InputGestures assign ALT-H for help